# What does the category of $G$-set look like when $G = C_p$?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. The category of $G$-set consists of finite $G$-sets as objects and $G$-equivariant maps as morphisms. Each finite $G$-set is isomorphic to a disjoint union of $G/H$'s, where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

My question is what does this category look like when $G$ is cyclic group of order prime  $p$? $G = C_p$ has only two subgroups: $\{e\}$ and $G$ itself. Denote $G/\{e\}$ by $\circ$ and denote $G/G$ by $\bullet$. The first question is what the subcategory over $\circ,\bullet$ looks like. More specificlly, how many $G$-equivariant maps from $\circ$ to $\circ$ are there? What about from $\bullet$ to $\circ$?

Comment: There's no point in labeling $G/1$ and $G/G$, since these are just $C_p$ and $1$ respectively. What do you mean by "subcategory over $G$, $1$"? There is exactly one equivariant map $C_p\to 1$, there are exactly $p$ equivariant maps $C_p\to C_p$, and there are no equivariant maps $1\to C_p$.

Comment: What are these subcategories you're talking about?

Comment: @anon the category with $\bullet$ and $\circ$ as objects and the morph isms are those between $\bullet$ and $\circ$ or automorhpisms of $\bullet$ or $\circ$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First observe that the underlying set of $\bullet$ has one element, so the action of $G$ on $\bullet$ must be trivial and also every $G$-set has exactly one map to $\bullet$. This in particular applies to $\circ$ and $\bullet$ itself. On the other hand, for a map from $\bullet$ to some $G$-set $X$, the image of the (only) element of $\bullet$ must be a fixpoint for the action of $G$.

The action of $G$ on $\circ$ is right multiplication (assuming here that $G$ acts from the right). Because (assuming $G \neq 1$) $\circ$ has no fixpoints there is no map from $\bullet$ to $\circ$.

Also, a map $f: \circ \to X$ to a $G$-set $X$ is already determined by the image $f(1)$, because we must have $f(g) = f(1\cdot g) = f(1)\cdot g$. Conversely, an element of $X$ corresponds to a map from $\circ$ to $X$ (If you have seen the Yoneda lemma you will recognize it here).